# Typescript error when trying to extend a generic variable in a parent class

Tags: typescript

Consider the following typescript code:

```
interface IHookable<THooks extends object> {
    trigger<THook extends keyof THooks>(hook: THook, parameters: THooks[THook]): void;
}

interface MainClass<TExtendedHooks extends object = {}> extends IHookable<{
    'firstHook': [MainClass],
    'secondHook': [MainClass]
} & TExtendedHooks> {}

class MainClass<TExtendedHooks extends object = {}> {
    innerFunction() {
        this.trigger('firstHook', [this]);
    }
}

/** The trigger function will be added to the MainClass with a mixin here, but it is ommited for brevity */

class ExtendingClass extends MainClass<{
    'thirdHook': [ExtendingClass]
}> {
    otherInnerFunction() {
        this.trigger('firstHook', [this]);
        this.trigger('thirdHook', [this]);
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve, is to create a class which exposes some hooks, and create an extending class, which may expose some other hooks as well, without touching the original hooks. The code itself works as expected, but typescript is complaining in the base class, that:

```
Argument of type '[this]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[MainClass<{}>] & TExtendedHooks["firstHook"]'.
  Type '[this]' is not assignable to type 'TExtendedHooks["firstHook"]'.(2345)
```

I presume I am getting this error, because typescript can not be sure, that my TExtendedHooks generic parameter, doesn't overwrite or extend one of the original, predefined hooks I am using. How could I solve this typescript error, so that the trigger functions for hooks that are introduced in the main class, can be callable in the main class code, without a given error?

Here's a playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAkD2mDWcBGANhADwAqWuAzshAB6QgAmNm+AVhAmAHzIDeAKGQjkYKMADmk6OUo5aDCMxo4IAT0wxkFbDio8AFAAs9ALh3yANMgAOcKHAC2ESFCoXd1ANpecAXQBKCwA3TGAmAG5BAF9BQVA3eCRkAFk4UABhQjgqKnIAUSVmCCZ5GnpGFmQ2Tm5kAF4BGL5K5WqMPQJiEiFRZAByGGB3MHkBi290rJy8-ythUQGqLkxmccnpkGzcqn9Y5AAyHSKq0vK+fjjBBFmaLZ28wuKmc70Kl9YOLjBG5svFiJQCBoAAxACuIG4wDWhkCAkB-WQAHoAFSotB2KAQKjglyY5zIGRgMCgSRiYwoaBQTBQZCU7HIfBcODglZidS2HEICS2X7GXLIECYZAAdzg6jEIpwwtFNkRSIxYAFvzIp3ab2oyGAVBAA1+bWYZIpKAARMNRvJTVjMFyoGBJTAaU4TfT3jVvtwFf0MXBmBS2a6Vgg1kw7A5nK5oMgqKZwYQw8zkExgDAYNBlL9lcoAHTILCi5Ah+Nh1AxzCEEIoZU62hQGlQb2iX3+qikwiEZBqCC2Cm1267GPicHccHYgD8yFRyKbfaoOfEUhkUEMQxGbfGNm8Nb2gWi-Ti1zRGLIlLEEmk0ZgkOhazFwA7TJQcCYrzDYBF2bSGW2d3vyuQOBkCcYA6FAekMxsfBwV+YBYNYJwQMgMMYFpJlsRCODJWneIBzyZB1SNEBJEeD4qnuH9SN6RF9WMEYyj0CZkG8QiU2I0j9haBF+kwbMoFQEAQSgCEoVJWF4T6JERB3BcL2XVcLQ3Ritx3IJ9ykudZKXaBVxrKAGNwAYVLo3d1JEQ9cLWNtgMou4BLbP0UiaEFCweO44WiJxbN2eywEciAtMvFc10tZTmK8mYfJAByoQgNSUWROcxVpfQbD9d9OW5XlfkkYAqxoYU6wbKhLOig0XjJUjfP8v4XIIir2PcvdBENNiSLssr-MC+SQqUwytwi38opipB4uRRKd0AwgqBFUUUpoQU4JjOME0EQaqs62Lup03qxjC7xWsqjqRrivcEqSuBptm+bAJoJbY0wEt4mPHQzzWQhJVsHIUgdLkqB5YA+W1GgQycL6fzJGxazgLMzwQS7pqlV1r1EmFoqh6KImrOG-zglZCG0acgA) as well.

**Side notes:**

The whole `IHookable` interface was created because we have a bunch of classes that should be able to trigger events, and they all do it the same way. For this, we created a "trait", and each of those classes should mixin the given trait. The interface is there, so that when someone tries to use the functions implemented by the trait, he gets intellisense and autocompletion support. For example:

```
interface SomeClass extends IHookable<{
 'specificHookForSomeClass': [string]
}>{}
class SomeClass {...}

interface SomeTotallyDifferentClass extends IHookable<{
 'specificHookForSomeTotallyDifferentClass': [number]
}> {}
interface SomeTotallyDifferentClass {...}

/** and consider a bunch of other classes in the above manner - with the trait, we won't be implementing the logic for the "trigger" function in each one of them, we just mixin the traits - by specifying the interface, when someone tries to call the trigger on a class that implements this interface, receives intellisense support and type validation, like below **/

const someTotallyDifferentClassInstance = new SomeTotallyDifferentClass();
someTotallyDifferentClassInstance.trigger('specificHookForSomeTotallyDifferentClass', ['incorrect string parameter']); // I am getting an error here, this trigger function would need a "number", and not a string
```

This was working greatly until now, but we would need to extend a class, let's say `SomeTotallyDifferentClass` and in the extension, we would like to give another option for the `trigger` function, that is callable on those instances. So what we tried, is give a generic variable to `SomeTotallyDifferentClass`, so when it is being extended, this generic may be supplied to extend the "hooks" for the class. It is working code wise, but typescript starts complaining, if I try to call the "trigger" function, from inside the class, outside the class it still works, and works as expected. I've also edited my playground link, to show an example of this.

Comment: Your playground link is broken.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wgDolN) work for you?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure if your playground link is working properly.

Comment: @jcalz I can not modify the interface, `IHookable` because it  is only to allow the class to know, that it will support the calling of the `trigger` function, but not the parameters of the function. Basically, I have a trait, that implements the functions requested by `IHookable`, and the classes that implement `IHookable` should mixin that trait, and provide the type of hooks that they are exposing

Comment: fixed the playground link in the meanwhile, thanks for noticing

Comment: What exactly are you allowed to modify?  I could suggest [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WkDqDw) where I don't touch `IHookable` at all, but I suspect it also won't suffice.

Comment: @jcalz this would work, but it defeats the purpose of the "hackish" way I am persuing - basically, I have a bunch of classes, that may "trigger" different things. Some of those classes can be extended, and those extensions may trigger additional things as well. I've written a trait, that adds the logic of these trigger functions, so that I don't have to implement it in all the classes that use it, and would like a way to give these classes autocompletion and intelisense support, when these trigger functions are being called. I make some edits to the post, to clarify.

Comment: strangely, typescript is only complaining if I try to call the method inside the class, thus I think the problem is that in the current scenario, he correctly infers that the "firstHook" method parameters may have been overwritten in the extending class, and you have no way to be sure, that it still requests a "MainClass" as the second parameter for the trigger function. Is there a way, I could tell typescript, that the base object will never be overwritten?

Comment: I don't understand why my versions are "defeating the purpose". Like, [here](https://tsplay.dev/WyqVxW) is another way.  Does it really matter that you merge into a pair of things instead of one thing?

Comment: @jcalz because of the constant need to redeclare the function signature in the interface, but this last method seems to be good - but I don't understand, how is this different, in the way I did things in my example, and why does this work and that one does not?

Comment: How about I back up and try to do it the way you're talking about, perhaps like [this version](https://tsplay.dev/W4ja7N).  Does that meet your needs? If so I will write up an answer explaining how it works.  (Note that your question "why doesn't my version work" in the comments is an *extra* question which I might touch on in my answer but isn't the main focus here.)

Comment: @jcalz the last version is perfect, that is exactly what I need! thank you, if you add as an answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulation of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) types is tricky; the compiler is not always able to make the sorts of "obvious" connections that a human being can.  If a type is not generic then the compiler can follow some reduction rules to compare different types.  But for generics it often just gives up.  Either it gives up by saying "I don't know what's assignable here so I'm going to reject everything", or by saying "I'm just going to replace the unknown generic type with its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) and hope that the substitution is good enough".  So complex types that depend on generic type parameters can generate both false positives and false negatives from the compiler.

It's sometimes possible to refactor things to turn an error situation (false or otherwise) into a non-error situation (again, possibly erroneously), but it's more of an art than a science and I don't know if I could give authoritative reasoning for exactly why one version breaks and another succeeds.

One way to convince the compiler that `this.trigger('firstHook', [this])` is acceptable inside `MainClass<T>` no matter what `T` is, is to [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` so that it cannot introduce a `firstHook` property that's incompatible.  Like this:

```
interface MainHook {
    'firstHook': [MainClass],
    'secondHook': [MainClass],
}

interface MainClass<T extends Partial<MainHook> & object = {}>
    extends IHookable<MainHook & T> { }

class MainClass<T extends Partial<MainHook> & object = {}> {
    innerFunction() {
        this.trigger('firstHook', [this]); // okay
    }
}
```

Since `T` is assignable to `Partial<MainHook>`, then `MainHook & T` will have a `firstHook` property assignable to `([MainClass] | undefined) & [MainClass]`, or `[MainClass]`.  And luckily the compiler is able to follow this logic to allow things to compile.

(Note the `& object` is there to prevent [weak type detection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#weak-type-detection), which doesn't help us.)

---

So great, that works.  But is that actually type safe?  Uh, I don't think so.  Given that `T["firstHook"]` can be *narrower* than `[MainClass]`, it's possible that `IHookable<MainHook & T>`'s `trigger()` method should *reject* an arbitrary `[MainClass]` input.  It looks like the compiler just compares against `T`'s constraint when checking.  So it's possible although unlikely for someone to craft a type that does bad things.

Why didn't your version work?  Again, not sure.  It presumably checked against `T["firstHook"]` and had no idea what it might be, and gave up in the "reject" direction instead of the "accept" direction. ‍♂️

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAkD2mDWcBGANhADwAqyEAHpCACYDOym+AVhAmAHzIDeAUMiHIwUYAHNx0EgGlKNCPSY4IAT0wxkZLgAoAFthwAuZDIA0yAA5wocALYRIUBibIBtGQF0AlCYBumMB0ANz8AL78-KBO8EjIALJwoFi4fILCAOQwwM5gKTgZJm6JoADChHAMDJ5m6UIZDByY9PmFyMVJIOWV1bURUeDQsSglXRVV5PK0jMgACjZgwHCEJKP5PABkzGwcYMgAvHxhXHVTijMYhgTEq535yFvafMj9CONMo90TFNTTTPNQRbLW7JQybbbsTgHI48ATCZCgEDQABiAFcQJxgM0dN40vD4WA9MAGAA6UQSKRQHRZHIMPKGDIWNyE4k+ULwiL9fhvHrIACiCnooHEXyYv3OH06opIcMyLKgdFaRQF02Fopq4Vhp0whOgqBASKgaIxi2xuNl+JERNJ5Mk0Gp2VyrSZLOq3nZlqtxLJYjtVIy8sVDJd1rZp05kQQzTpyDsUve+rpcAxKEOSIA7gl4z0caE42UEyAkymfRT7TSncH2vmxj1E2Bk0gw9zo3txUKQCLC8W4mmIJmVec1e9c-x23Rh3Wiw2S7bKQ7afTcIzq9mqvXGxA2ch+DXRRvZ775xW6c72uPJ+vp5vt5EgA)